# How to get server_name from url?

Tags: python

I have ( for example ) a link:

```
http://10.100.0.178:8134/hds-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent.f4m
```

How to get server_name (http://10.100.0.178:8134/ ) from this link ? Any standard function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html [deprecated]

### Updated due to luckydonald's comment

[For Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

[For Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.pa%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Brse)

Comment: i think that would just give the ip, not the name

Comment: Try this. str(o.scheme + "//" + o.netloc)

Comment: Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse
Python 2: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html
Link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

```
import urlparse

a = 'http://10.100.0.178:8134/hds-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent.f4m'
output = '{0.scheme}://{0.netloc}'.format(urlparse.urlsplit(a))

# output == 'http://10.100.0.178:8134'
```

Comment: For Python 3 community: 'urlparse' has been replaced by 'urllib.parse'

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
from urlparse import urlparse
ip = urlparse('http://173.194.64.104').hostname
socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
```

Comment: Interesting, but this does not answer the question (no port info returned)

Comment: what was your argument for urlparse?

Answer (score 0):

well, please consider that you could have multiple domain-names for one ip. socket.gethostbyaddr would only deliver the first (or default) hostname for this ip.